# What is the best way to convert a string of 0's and 1's into byte[] in java

Tags: java, byte

My program should get a path for a text file as input.
The text is just 1's and 0's and the program needs to read it as bytes.
This is what I got so far, it's working but I know there's a better way

```
public void transform(String input_File)
{
    File file = new File(input_file);

    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String org_text = null;
    String byte_val;
    try {
        while ((org_text = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < org_text.length();i += 8)
            {
                byte_val = org_text.substring(i, i+8);
                int ch = Integer.parseInt(byte_val, 2);
                //some more lines here, but it dosn't matter

            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you not use `getBytes` once you've read the string?

Comment: You could try `new BigInteger(text,2).toByteArray()`.

Comment: Hi @AntonH I can use or not use whatever i want.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Perfect! Thank You!